# How to get the data from QTableWidget?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt4

I have created a `QTableWidget` which contains the file name and its size. Now I need to retrieve the file name from `TableWidget` and need to store it in a File. Can anyone help me to how to do this?, is there any function to retrive the text from column?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using the method

```
QTableWidgetItem* item(int row, int column) const
```

Used like this:

```
int row = 1;
int col = 1;
QTableWidgetItem* theItem = theTableWidget->item(row, col);
```

and extract the text using QTableWidgetItem method

```
QString text () const
```

Used like this:

```
QString theText = theItem->text();
```

Comment: "Thanks a lot :)" is best expressed by [by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Precise answer. You saved my day! :)